# Slideshow circles bottom chopped off on MAC

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using well known JQuery plugin called Cycle for slideshow on this site:
[bybyweb.com/pbm](http://bybyweb.com/pbm)

and i have problem - on windows (all newest browsers) all works fine, BUT on MAC (lion 10.7.5, one test machine; don't know version of clients OS-> second test machine...) there is problem...

Problem: **circles have the bottom chopped off.**  (slideshow navigation circles, you will see it). Tested in Firefox, Safari and Chrome!

Relevant css:

```
#slider_nav {
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:27px;
    z-index:999;
    left:392px;
    top:455px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.slideli{
    width:24px;
    height:27px;
    padding:0 24px 0 0;
    background-image:url(../images/gray-dot.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-position:top;
    margin:0;
}

.activeSlide {      
    width:24px;
    height:27px;
    text-decoration:none; 
    padding:0 24px 0 0;
    background-image:url(../images/white-dot.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:top;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin:0;
}
```

I have set higher height than needed, removed margins, paddings... but no success - obviously something else is problem here, and i would appreciate any tip/advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this line on your JS:

```
return '<li'+s+' class="slideli"><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>';
```

Which creates these lines:

```
<li0 class="slideli">
<li1 class="slideli">
<li2 class="slideli">
<li3 class="slideli">
<li4 class="slideli">
```

This is of course illegal.

---

Also, I did some changes on *slideli* CSS. It's supposed to help:

```
.slideli {
    background-image: url("../images/gray-dot.png");
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;          // Added
    height: 27px;
    margin-right: 5px;              // Added
    padding: 0;                     // Changed
    width: 24px;
}
```

Fix that and tell us if that solved the problem

Comment: Thank you! Changed css solved problem. (can't change jquery/js part - slideshow will not work in that case).

Comment: The problem was that the `li` elements were of `inline display`, and your `width` and `height` styling didn't work on them. The padding was used to make it the proper width. There's probably a difference on the way the `padding` or `line-height` are rendered in Mac, and so your element was cut. Changing it to `inline-block display` lets the `width` and `height` work properly.